# How to remove ControllerName from a Rails Resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I wish to map new_user path of the user resource to 'ROOT_DOMAIN/new' URL. My routes.rb looks something like this:

```
  #new_user GET      /users/new(.:format)                        users#new

  # User Resource
  match 'new', :to => 'users#new', via: [:get, :post]
  resources :users do
    collection do
      match 'new', :to => 'users#new', via: [:get, :post]
    end  
  end
```

So while I'm able to hit the /new URL to the desired action with

```
  match 'new', :to => 'users#new', via: [:get, :post]
```

but the new_user path still leads to '/users/new'. How to remove the controller_name from the new_user method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new_user_path takes you to `user#new` because that's how rails build resourceful routes. Have a look at [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers) to learn more. You need to pass the as: option to your routes in order to give them proper helper methods like:

```
post '/home' => "home#index", as: :home
```

This will give you two helpers home_path and home_url

Now you have

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    match 'new', :to => 'users#new', via: [:get, :post]
  end  
end
```

If you do *rake routes in your terminal* you'll see that new_user helpers are assigned to `user#new`. *You need to give it a different path helper and then assign your new_user helpers to your custom route*

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    match 'new', :to => 'users#new', via: [:get, :post], as: :old_new_user
  end  
end
```

and then you can use your new_user helper for your custom route

```
match 'new', :to => 'users#new', via: [:get, :post], as: :new_user
```

You can check your path helper by doing `rake routes` in terminal